# How can I use OAuth authentication in twitter API?

Tags: javascript, api, twitter, oauth

I'm trying to connect to the new twitter API. As I understand, I cannot use anymore base64 protocol for authentication. 
Normally, I would do something like this:

```
request = Promise.promisifyAll( request );

var apikey = 'some-api-key';
var twitterUrl = 'some-twitter-api-url-endpoint'

request.getAsync( {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': BasicAuthGenerator( apikey ) // returns something like this: 'Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ=='
    },  
    url: 'some-twitter-api-url'
} )
.get( 1 )
.then( console.log );
```

But now, as I understand, twitter does not support the Basic Auth. I simply can't understand the oAuth methods. I have read the introduction book and searched on this topic and still did not understand how to implement it. Can I use it in the request headers? Should it go through another oAuth method? Can I pass my params without importing another 3rd party library?

I'm using node.js.

If someone could simplify it for me, that would be great.
Thanks before

Answer (score 0):

Writing your own implementation of OAuth is probably not the best use of your time, as there are already many libraries available for developers to use.

If you visit [this page on the OAuth website](http://oauth.net/code/) and scroll down to the "JavaScript" section, you will see several libraries from which you can choose.